# Is the statement "$x=3$ if and only if $x^2=9$" false, or only sometimes true?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

In Terence Tao's Analysis I, he says that "the statement '$x=3$ if and only if $x^2=9$'" is false. However, isn't it more accurate to say that this statement is not always true? Isn't this statement true  sometimes (i.e. when $x\neq-3)$ and false other times (i.e. when $x=-3$). Perhaps the $\forall x$ quanitifer had been left implicit, and what he really means is that the following statement is false:
$$
\forall x:x=3 \leftrightarrow x^2=9 \, .
$$
However, at this point in the book he hadn't introduced quantifiers, and so I'm unsure what is intended.

To add to my confusion, in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1202548/if-x2-x-then-x-1-is-this-statement-true-or-false) post, it states that the meaning of "If $A$, then $B$" is "whenever $A$ is true, $B$ is true". According to this definition, the statement "$x=3$ if and only if $x^2=9$" is plainly false. However, the negation of $A \leftrightarrow B$ is $A\leftrightarrow \neg B$. So the negation of "$x=3$ if and only if $x^2=9$" is "$x=3$ if and only if $x^2\neq9$", which is also false according to this definition in the linked post. A statement and its negation can't both be false, so I'm unsure what's gone wrong.

Comment: I agree with your analysis. I would recon that the author was being a little informal.

Comment: Something that is "sometimes false" is false.

Comment: The statement '$x=3$ if and only if $x^2=9$' contains the implication $x^2=9 \Rightarrow x=3,$ which (in general) is wrong, as $(-3)^2 = 9.$ If, however, we impose further restrictions on $x$, we can obtain similar statements which are true: $\forall x \in [0,\infty) : x^2 = 9 \Leftrightarrow x = 3.$

Comment: "If and only if" means "whenever" both ways not "some of the time"

Comment: [randall](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/464495/randall.) I think there is subtlety there. It may be true in certain models and untrue in others. I think the OP is running up against the distinction of satisfiability vs tautology vs unsatisfyability

Comment: See page 312: "If x is an integer, then the statement “If $x = 2$, then $x^2 = 4$” is true, regardless of whether x is actually equal to 2 or not (though this statement is only likely to be useful when x is equal to 2)." Why so? because for every value of $x$, if the antecedent is false it is Ok and if the antecedent is true (i.e., $x=2$) then also the consequent is true. Thus, the author is reading - as common mathematical practice - an open formula as universally quantified.

Comment: If we apply the same approach (as you are doing above) to the bi-conditional we get false, because for $x=-3$ we have that $x^2=9$ is true.

Comment: In general, if you have two statements, $P$ and $Q$, where $P \implies Q$ and where it is not the case that $Q \implies P$, then the statement  $P \iff Q$ is false, by definition of the $\iff$ operator.

Comment: @TonyK: Please see the discussion below. In order to make sense of the statement $x=3 \leftrightarrow x^2=9$, it has to be clear that there is a quantifier over $x$ (either implicitly or explicitly). Otherwise $x=3 \leftrightarrow x^2=9$ does not have a true value at all because $x$ is a free variable.

Comment: *it states that the meaning of "If A, then B" is "whenever A is true, B is true"* Not quite: yes, their meanings can overlap, however, the former might mean that $A\to B$ is true in the current interpretation, while the latter means either that $A\to B$ is a validity or is universally true. The word "whenever" indicates that we are considering $A$ (and $B$)'s truth as the interpretation varies or as its predicate variable varies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indeed, in the statement "$x = 3$ if and only if $x^2 = 9$", the universal quantifier ("for all $x$ it is true that...") has been left implicit. As a logical statement, $x = 3 \leftrightarrow x^2 = 9$ does not have a truth value, as $x$ is still a free variable.

This explains the problem with negation: although the negation of $A \leftrightarrow B$ is $A \leftrightarrow \neg B$, the negation of $\forall x (A(x) \leftrightarrow B(x))$ is $\exists x (A(x) \leftrightarrow \neg B(x))$. And indeed *there is* an $x$ such that $x = 3$ is false but $x^2 = 9$ is true.

Comment: Wow, there are so many explainations here.

Comment: Thank you for this. You and Paul Frost's answers seem to be the only ones that have understood and addressed my confusion.

Comment: [Joe](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/623665/joe) I second that. The other answers all contain misunderstandings.

Comment: @user2628206: Thank you. By the way, if you want to notify someone when you comment, then you should write ``@name``. See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Comment: Ah thanks! @Joe

Comment: I have a question: I've done some research and it turns out that formulae that contain a free variable are not assigned truth values. Only closed formulae are assigned truth values. So to give a formula we have to bind all the variables within it, either by putting a quantifier over them, or assigning a particular value to one of the variables. Here is one edge case I need to clarify: the words "let $x=5$" binds the variable $x$. However, do the words "let $y$ be a solution to $y^2=36$" bind the variable $y$, given that this equation has two solutions?

Comment: Good question, but I think you are making a category error. Variable binding usually refers to connecting a variable to a quantifier **within** a given formula. The variable is said to be 'within the scope' of the quantifier. The Let statement is made when writing proofs in a non formal (as in formal system) way when one wants to introduce variable that satisfies a certain condition to reason upon. How this is done formally depends on the proof system that one is using, but there is a clear precedent for its usage in prose. These are, to my understanding, fundamentally different processes

Answer (score 4):

In fact the quantifier $\forall x$ is implicit here. Although Tao has not formally introduced quantifiers when he considers the statetement in question on p. 358, he has made it clear *verbally* what is going on. Quotation:

> Thus for instance, if $x$ is a real number, then the statement "$x = 3$ if and only if $2x = 6$" is true: this means that whenever $x = 3$ is true, then $2x = 6$ is true, and whenever $2x = 6$ is true, then $x = 3$ is true. On the other hand, the statement "$x = 3$ if and only if $x^2 = 9$" is false; while it is true that whenever $x = 3$ is true, $x^2 = 9$ is also true, it is not the case that whenever $x^2 = 9$ is true, that $x = 3$ is also automatically true (think of what happens when $x = -3$).

Thus the claim is

> If $x$ is a real number, then the statement "$x = 3$ if and only if $x^2 = 9$" is false.

This is the verbal formulation of

> $\forall x \in \mathbb R$ : $x = 3 \leftrightarrow x^2 = 9$

which is false.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, Paul. It does help to put things in context. I asked Mees de Vries this question, but I'd also like to hear your opinion: I've done some research and it turns out that formulae that contain a free variable are not assigned truth values. Only closed formulae are assigned truth values. So to give a formula we have to bind all the variables within it, either by putting a quantifier over them, or assigning a particular value to one of the variables.

Comment: Here is one edge case I need to clarify: the words "let $x=5$" binds the variable $x$. However, do the words "let $y$ be a solution to $y^2=36$" bind the variable $y$, given that this solution has two solutions?

Comment: @Joe Yes. On p. 373 Tao writes *The symbol $\forall$ can be used instead of "For all", thus for instance "$\forall x \in X : P(x)$ is true" or "$P(x)$ is true $\forall x \in X$" is synonymous with "$P(x)$ is true for all $x\in X$".* You see that $X$ specifies the possible values for the free variable $x$ occurring in $P(x)$. The phrase "Let $y$ be a solution to $y^2 = 36$" itself is not a statement, but it specifies the values $y$ may take in some statement $P(y)$ depending on the free variable $y$.

Comment: Formally you can define $Y = \{ y \in \mathbb R\mid y^2 = 36\}$ and then you get "$\forall y \in Y : P(y)$" which may be true or false.

Comment: Okay, but when we write $\forall y \in Y: P(y)$, $y$ is a bound variable. Is that correct?

Comment: @Joe Yes, correct.